# How to calculate how often to poll the server for new data?

Tags: polling

Is there a formula, or generally accepted approach?

Should I be measuring database updates and averaging their frequency then using that to determine how often clients should poll the server?

I would like all clients to have up to date data, but there's no point in polling the server every second if the data only changes once a week.

---

It is a Browser based app, with MySql on a server.

I thought that I would send a CRC of the data from the client with each poll. If it matches, then I don't need to re-send the data.

I am still unsure how often to poll, though.

Comment: Consider polling often, but maintaining a "changed" flag server-side that will let almost all requests return immediately with (almost) no computational load.

Comment: What kind of client applications? What kind of database (so what DBMS)? Some databases are able to push events. Some client technologies may have asynchronous communications (Websockets in browsers). Smartphone users might be pissed off if your app was making an HTTP request every ten seconds. You should improve your question by telling more

Comment: You can not guarantee to have every one be 100% up to date, as in some sense, the information is stale as soon as it leaves the server.  For that reason, we use mechanisms of timestamps, transaction counters, reservations, push & pull, etc... to ensure that the client can get work done and make changes in spite of the inherent staleness involved with networked computing.

Comment: If the likelihood of updates varies from datum to datum, the server could send Time To Live values to the client that tell it when to poll again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a forumla, or generally accepted approach?

There is no formula.  Averaging will not work reliably.  If an update happens on Sunday and the client polls on Mondays, its data is only one day out of date.  If the next update happens on Tuesday, the data will be out of date until the following Monday's poll.

The generally-accepted approach is to identify a hard requirement for how fresh a client's data must be and make decisions based on that.

> I would like all clients to have up to date data...

This isn't a requirement, it's a vague statement about what would be nice to have.  What is the quantitative definition of up-to-date?  In other words, how far behind the master copy can a client's data set be and still be considered up-to-date?  Answer that question and you have a hard number for the minimum update interval and how often you have to poll.  You can then weigh that against your other requirements and figure out if the whole set of requirements is reasonable and make changes accordingly.